# How can I plot a circle region of density plot

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a 2-dimensions function with density plot:

function define:

```
FTn[x_, y_, j_, pt_] := Fit[pt, Catenate[Table[Table[x^n y^(k - n), {n, 0, k}], {k, 0, j}]], {x, y}];

RFT[x_, y_, n_, pt_] := Module[{pl, RF, RFf},
   pl = FTn[a, b, n, pt];
   RF[s_, t_] := pl /. {a -> s, b -> t};
   RF[x, y]
   ];

pt={{3., 0., 2922.8}, {70., 0., 2917.48}, {28., 28., 2941.44}, {0., 70., 
  2942.56}, {-28., 28., 2917.72}, {-70., 0., 2927.08}, {-28., -28., 
  2936.56}, {0., -70., 2902.32}, {28., -28., 2919.12}, {102., 0., 
  2961.32}, {57., 72., 2972.48}, {0., 102., 2972.16}, {-57., 72., 
  2957.04}, {-102., 0., 2974.72}, {-57., -72., 2954.56}, {0., -102., 
  2966.2}, {57., -72., 2932.16}, {127., 0., 3134.8}, {102., 42., 
  2986.4}, {90., 90., 3138.88}, {42., 102., 2992.76}, {0., 127., 
  3132.8}, {-42., 102., 3005.48}, {-90., 90., 3126.88}, {-102., 42., 
  2996.12}, {-127., 0., 3122.8}, {-102., -42., 2988.12}, {-90., -90., 
  3110.96}, {-42., -102., 2994.12}, {0., -127., 3120.88}, {42., -102.,
   2985.48}, {90., -90., 3128.64}, {102., -42., 2996.24}, {147., 0., 
  4105.28}, {129., 54., 3463.08}, {104., 104., 4107.2}, {54., 129., 
  3467.84}, {0., 147., 4077.72}, {-54., 129., 3467.4}, {-104., 104., 
  4106.84}, {-129., 54., 3470.44}, {-147., 0., 4084.72}, {-129., -54.,
   3466.56}, {-104., -104., 4116.4}, {-54., -129., 
  3475.64}, {0., -147., 4113.2}, {54., -129., 3481.88}, {104., -104., 
  4150.4}, {129., -54., 3463.08}}
```

And also using the density plot function like this:

```
DensityPlot[RFT[x, y, 12, pt], {x, -#3, #3}, {y, -#3, #3},
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {#1, #2}}], {#1, #2}}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 15, Bold], 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 300],
   PlotRange -> {{-#3, #3}, {-#3, #3}},
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {#1, #2}}],
   PlotRange -> Full,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 150^2],
   BoundaryStyle -> Red,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   FrameLabel -> {"HF-FTP(%)", "LF-FTP(%)"},
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, 10, Black],
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["function", 28, Bold,
      Black],
   ImageSize -> 350
   ] &[2600, 4500, 150]
```

But the output result is not the circle region:

[image]
How can I fixed the code to plot a circle region?

Comment: Did you try to increase  `PlotPoints`?

Comment: I have tried to use the PlotPoints->100, but its still got the same result...

Comment: Try using the plot range `PlotRange->{{-#3,#3},{-#3,#3},All}`. I'm guessing that some clipping is going on near the edges of the circle where things seem to be changing very fast. You can also check this by adding `ClippingStyle->Cyan` and seeing if a cyan ring fills the circle appropriately out near the edges. Your region function looks good.

Comment: PlotRange->{{-#3,#3},{-#3,#3},All} is very useful and solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the output is in fact a circular region, but your function "dies out" before you hit the edge of the circle. Drawing a circle around the region...

```
{DensityPlot[RFT[x, y, 12, pt], {x, -#3, #3}, {y, -#3, #3}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {#1, #2}}], {#1, #2}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 15, Bold], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300], PlotRange -> {{-#3, #3}, {-#3, #3}}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {#1, #2}}], 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 150^2], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"HF-FTP(%)", "LF-FTP(%)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, 10, Black], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["function", 28, Bold, Black], 
 ImageSize -> 350] &[2600, 4500, 150],Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 150]]}//Show
```

[image]

If you change the input to the `DensityPlot` a little (and I have no idea what this means to change it) then it looks nice. Changed parameter highlighted.

```
 DensityPlot[RFT[x, y, **6**, pt], etc...
```

[image]

Edit...

Fiddled with this a little more (interesting problem) and I think you are overfitting your `pt` data with a 12th order polynomial. Unless you have a physics-based reason to use that order, a reduced order would be better. The 6th order fit I used above is better. Just playing around, here is a `ContourPlot` of the 12th order fit with the boundaries extended outward. Note lack of symmetry, although I believe your points being fitted is symmetric.

[image]

Comment: I know RFT[x, y, **6**, pt] can plot a circle graphic, but it's not precision...

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to manually sample. This is a bit slow but gives you full control:

```
r = 150;
n = 100; (* resoluiton control *)
z = {{##}, 
    RFT[##, 12, pt]} & @@@ ((Position[DiskMatrix[n], 1] - n - 1) r/n);
range = MinMax@z[[All, 2]];
g = Graphics[{{ColorData[
         "Rainbow"][(#[[2]] - range[[1]])/(range[[2]] - range[[1]])],
       Rectangle[#[[1]] - r/n/2 {1, 1}, #[[1]] + r/n/2 {1, 1}]} & /@ 
     z, {Red, Thickness[1/n/4], Circle[{0, 0}, r + r/n/2]}}];

Show[g, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {-175, -175}]
```

[image]

just to see whats happening at the edges:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten /@ z, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]